# Proving two functions are monotonically related

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives

I've been relying on stackexchange a lot lately but this is my first time asking a question. A lot of searching has yielded no answer so hopefully someone can help out.

I'm trying to find (and prove) whether two functions are monotonically related.

By monotonically related I mean that, for two functions, $f(x)$ and $g(x)$, if $f(x_i)<f(x_j)$ then $g(x_i)<g(x_j)$. In other words: $f(x_i)-f(x_j)$ must have the same sign as $g(x_i)-g(x_j)$ for all values of i and j.

To get more specific, my understanding of this is that two functions could be shown to be monotonically related by **proving that the function that relates $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ is a monotonic function.** I believe what is meant by this is that $f(x)=h(g(x))$ and $h$ has to be a monotonic function.

This is about as far as I can get. I have no idea how to find a function that relates two other functions let alone how to prove said function is a monotonic function. If anyone could help with either of these issues, either showing how to find a function that relates two other functions or more generally how to show that two functions are monotonically related, it would be greatly appreciated.

For reference, the functions I am looking at are the following three:

$$f(x)=\frac{(a-x)^2}{a(2a-x)(b-x)}$$
$$f(x)=\frac{(a-x)}{a(b-x)}$$
$$f(x)=\frac{(a-x)}{a(2a-x)}$$

where x, a and b are all integers greater than 0 and x<=a and x<=b

Comment: From left to right: you may find such $h$ for any monotonic functions: let $x=g^{-1}(y)$ (monotonic function has inverse) and so $f(g^{-1}(y))=h(y)$

Comment: @Michael Galuza: I'm not sure if your allowed assume that $f$ or $g$ are themselves monotonic.

Comment: Here is a good post explaining the concept of "monotonically related": http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/781503/what-does-monotonically-related-mean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few questions in this post, so I'll just try to answer one of them. Hopefully I've interpreted it correctly. The quesiton: say $f$ and $g$ are monotonically related. Then there is a monotonic function $h$ such that $f = h∘g$, where $∘$ is function composition.

First, define monotonically related. The function $f$ if monotonically related to $g$ if $f(x) < f(y)$ implies $g(x) < g(y)$. The definition as I've given it may be strengthened to an equivalence instead of an implication but it's all we need for now. I.e. note that the order of $f$ and $g$ matters according to this definition.

Now, it is easy to see that $g(x) = g(y)$ implies $f(x) = f(y)$. Otherwise, $f(x) < f(y)$ or $f(y) < f(x)$, and in either case by our definition of monotonic relatedness then $g(x) \neq g(y)$. Call this result (1).

OK, now for any function we can always define a set valued "inverse". In other words $g^{-1}(y) = \{x | g(x) = y\}$.

Now, we can also define a function $f_s$ as follows. The domain of $f_s$ is the set of all sets whose image is the same under $f$. That is, $f_s$ takes as its argument a set $S_y = \{x | f(x) = y\}$. The value of $f_s(S_y) = y$.

Now, we can define our function $h$. Define $h = f_s∘g^{-1}$. To show that this definition is always possible, consider the result (1). This says that whenever $g(x) = g(y)$ then $f(x) = f(y)$. Now, for all values $u, v$ in the set $g^{-1}(y)$, we know by definition that $g(u) = g(v)$ and so by (1) $f(u) = f(v)$, so the set is a valid input argument for $f_s$ and the definition of $h$ makes sense.

Now, we can easily show that $h∘g = f$. We know by definition of $h$ that $h∘g(x) = f_s∘g^{-1}∘g(x)$. Now, we know that $x$ must be in the set $g^{-1}∘g(x)$, and we know that the value of $f_s$ is the value of $f$ for any value in that set, so after applying $f_s$ we get $f(x)$, as required.

---

Now that we've defined such a $h$, we need to show that it's monotonic. Well for this we need to strengthen the definition of monotonically related from the earlier one to an equivalence. So now we have also that $g(x) < g(y)$ implies $f(x) < f(y)$. I have a feeling this is the standard definition anyway, because the word "related" has no hint of direction in it.

Now, let's show the monotonicity of $h$. We note that the domain of $h$ is the range of $g$. So to show $h$ is monotonic we just need to show for some $g(x) < g(y)$ that $h(g(x)) < h(g(y))$. But by our definition of $h$, we know that this amounts to $f(x) < f(y)$, which follows directly from monotonic relatedness.

---

I'm not sure how useful this is. It looks like you're trying to show something specific, involving the particular functions you've posted. Hopefully it helped in some way.

---

EDIT: We can also prove the converse of the above. That is, given a monotonic $h$ such that $f = h∘g$ then $f$ and $g$ are monotonically related. To prove this, we need to show two things: that $f(x) < f(y)$ implies $g(x) < g(y)$ and vice versa.

So let's prove $f(x) < f(y)$ implies $g(x) < g(y)$. Well from our assumptions $f = h∘g$ and $f(x) < f(y)$, then we get $h(g(x)) < h(g(y))$. Now we know that $g(x) \neq g(y)$, otherwise $h(g(x)) < h(g(x))$, which is clearly false. So, assuming a total ordering, we have either $g(x) < g(y)$ or $g(x) > g(y)$. Well, by monotonicity of $h$, $g(x) > g(y)$ implies $h(g(x)) > h(g(y))$ which contradicts our earlier $h(g(x)) < h(g(y))$. So we're left to conclude $g(x) < g(y)$, finishing this case.

The second case is to show $g(x) < g(y)$ implies $f(x) < f(y)$. This is simpler. We want to show $f(x) < f(y)$, which by our earlier assumption is that same as $h(g(x)) < h(g(y))$. Now this follows directly from $g(x) < g(y)$ and the monotonicity of $h$.

Comment: Thanks heaps for this Colm!

From my interpretation of your response, you've shown that, assuming $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are monotonically related and $h∘g = f$ then $h$ will be a monotonic function.

In my case, I don't know that $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are monotonically related but am instead trying to actually find what function $h$ would be given some formulas for f(x) and g(x) and then show whether $h$ is a monotonic function. 

I'm hoping I've learnt enough from your response to figure out the answer myself but if possible, an example of how to find h with any two functions would be hugely useful!

Comment: Hi Cam. What I've shown is actually a little stronger. I show that whenever $f$ and $g$ are monotonically related, there always *exists* a $h$ such that $f = h∘g$ *and* $h$ is monotonic. Just to put this into logic, suppose $M(f, g)$ denotes monotonic relatedness and $m(h)$ denotes monotonicity of $h$. Then I show $M(f, g) \Rightarrow \exists h, f = h∘g \wedge m(h)$. On the other hand, your interpretation given in the comment is weaker: $M(f, g) \wedge f = h∘g \Rightarrow m(h)$.

Comment: To address the rest of your comment: it's not always possible to define such a $h$. That's why we need the assumption of monotonic relatedness in the first place. I need more space so I'll post why in another answer.

Comment: I've also shown the converse in the first answer. So now you have two results to work with: 1) monotonically related functions always have a monotonic function relating them 2) a monotonic function relating two functions is enough to show that they're monotonically related.

Comment: Ahh I see!! Point 2) is exactly what I needed. Marked as the correct answer. Thanks so much Colm!

Comment: No problem. It was a nice proof to work on.

Comment: Just to quickly note: I think in your edit when you said "...$g(x)>g(y)$ implies $h(g(x))>h(g(x))$ which contradicts our earlier $h(g(x))<h(g(x))$" you meant to say "...$g(x)>g(y)$ implies $h(g(x))>h(g(y))$ which contradicts our earlier $h(g(x))<h(g(y))$".

Also, am I right in thinking $h$ is actually assumed to be monotonically increasing in this proof? For my purposes, that is actually fine but thought I'd point it out for anyone else reading.

Comment: Well spotted- I've fixed the edit now! Yes- you are right. In the first proof, we show that monotonic relatedness implies the existence of a monotonic $h$ relating the functions. In the second proof, we show that a monotonic $h$ relating the functions implies monotonic relatedness. The assumption of said $h$ is given in the line: "That is, given a monotonic $h$ such that...". EDIT: By monotonic I actually mean monotonically increasing.

Comment: But it would all work just as easily if all the definitions were changed for monotonically decreasing functions.

Answer (score 0):

From the comments here is another question that I'll address: given any $f$ and $g$, can we always define a $h$ such that $f = h∘g$? Then answer is no. We demonstrate this with a counterexample. Take $f(x) = x$ and $g(x) = x^2$. Notice that $f$ is invertible but strictly speaking $g$ is not. This is the key property underlying the counterexample.

Now, we assume towards a contradiction that there is some $h$ such that $f = h∘g$. Equivalently this is $f(x) = h(g(x))$ for all $x$. Then $f(1) = h(g(1))$ so $1 = h(1)$. But also $f(-1) = h(g(-1))$ so $-1 = h(-1^2) = h(1)$. So $h(1) = -1 = 1$, which is a contradiction of the fact that $-1 \neq 1$.